# Refresh page on scroll to top of page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, autoload

I am creating a website in `php`, in which I want a division to `reload` by `javascript` when the user scroll to the top of the page.

Can anyone guide me how to do this with example?

Comment: i have not done anything yet.

Comment: Harjeet, you  can try calling  a specified function when a specified position in page is touched .

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [ask advise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using something like jQuery you can do it like this;

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 

   var offset = 50;

   if( $(window).scrollTop() <= offset ) {

   // Reload your division    
   //

   }

 });
```

Note; the .scroll function is firing each pixel you scroll, for browserload you might want to add a timeout for this

Comment: That WILL cause the page to reload if the user scrolls down a few pixels from the top!
Additional logic to make sure the user has scrolled down first would be necessary to make it function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the scrollTop value. Simple example:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ( $(window).scrollTop <= 30 ) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```